# Creating objects within an existing object in Python

Tags: python, class, object, inner-classes

I would like to create an object that holds and creates different objects within itself.
I have an outer class and inner classes, like this:

```
class Outer:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def sayHello(self):
        print "Hello " + self.name

    class Inner1:
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

    class Inner2(Inner1):
        pass

    class Inner3(Inner1):
        pass
new = outer("new")
```

And then new needs to make on object of inner2 or inner3... 
I tried it with `new.inner2()`
but I don´t get the result I want.
Any tips?

Comment: 1. Why do you have nested classes? 2. Given that it's named `Inner2` not `inner2`, why did you try `new.inner2()`?

Comment: The names are just for example. I want an object thats individual and can becreated by the user and that object should be able to make other objects within itself. allso provided by the user.
because i want the new object to make a new innerclass.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you give some context; what problem are you actually trying to solve? Nested classes are rarely necessary in Python, and the only problem with your code so far is that: 1. it isn't syntactically valid without `pass` in the bodies of the nested subclasses; and 2. you're not typing the class name in the correct case.

Comment: Are you trying to instantiate an `Inner1` in the global scope?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you would do nested classes and nested instantiations.  When you're embedding the classes, you're only embedding the types.  You have to create the instances in `self.__init__`

(If you're trying to do global inner instances shared among all Outer instances please update your question.)

```
class Outer(object):

    class Inner1(object):
        pass

    class Inner2(Inner1):
        pass

    class Inner3(Inner2):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        self.inner1 = Outer.Inner1()
        self.inner2 = Outer.Inner2()
        self.inner3 = Outer.Inner3()

outer = Outer()

print outer.inner1
print outer.inner2
print outer.inner3
```

Note that you don't have to actually use nested classes for this -- your classes can be defined outside of your class, and is sometimes preferred as simpler and more Pythonic:

```
class Inner1(object):
    pass

class Inner2(Inner1):
    pass

class Inner3(Inner2):
    pass

class Outer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.inner1 = Inner1()
        self.inner2 = Inner2()
        self.inner3 = Inner3()

outer = Outer()

print outer.inner1
print outer.inner2
print outer.inner3
```

Sometimes you'll also see a pattern of...

```
class Inner1(object):
   pass

class Outer(object):
   Inner1 = Inner1
```

to make a "handy" reference to the class inside the class.  This is often used with custom exceptions that the class might throw.

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1765716/2077386) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376127/is-it-a-good-practice-to-make-nested-class-in-python) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674788/are-static-inner-classes-a-good-idea-or-poor-design) different opinions on whether nesting the classes is preferred.

Comment: "and sometimes this is preferred" should be "and usually this is preferred" ;)

Comment: @AaronTaggart yeah, was just researching that!

Answer (score 2):

Honestly inner classes are not generally a good idea, especially if you're instantiating them outside of the "containing" class.

But to answer your question, basically the inner class is just declared in a different scope, so you need to reference the scope it is in.

```
# Changed to a capitol letter as that is more conventional
class Outer:
    name = ""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def sayHello(self):
        print ("Hello" + self.name)

    class Inner1:
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

    class Inner2(Inner1):
        pass

    class Inner3(Inner1):
        pass

newOuter = Outer("newOuter")
newInner2 = Outer.Inner2("newInner2")
```

Comment: *Honestly inner classes are not generally a good idea, especially if you're declaring them outside of the "containing" class.* -- is this really what you meant to say?  What do you mean?

Comment: I meant instantiating, not declaring :)